# I want to combine JavaScript Objects with the same variable name

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, javascript-objects, nested-for-loop

Right now, If i run for loop

```
{“FirstName” : “Kim”}
{“LastName” : “hana”}
{“Phone” : “010-1234-5648”}
{“Email” : “abc@gmail.com”}
```

It comes out like this.
But the result I want is

```
{“FirstName” : “Kim”, “LastName” : “hana”, “Phone” : “010-1234-5648”, “Email” : “abc@gmail.com”}
```

I want to make it come out like this.
What should I do?

This is my code that I just wrote.

```
function testRun(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var LastRow = ss.getLastRow();
    var LastCol = ss.getLastColumn();

    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 1; i<=LastCol; i ++){
        var fieldName = ss.getRange(1,i).getValue();
        arr.push(fieldName);
    }

    //arr = [FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email]

    for(var i =2;i<=LastRow;i++){
        for(var j=1;j<=LastCol;j++){
            var payload =  Utilities.jsonStringify({
              [arr[j-1]] : ss.getRange(i,j).getValue()}
            );
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your showing script, it seems that `payload` is not used.
- When `getValue()` is used in a loop, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

When these points are reflected in a sample script for achieving your goal, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

When your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

```js
function testRun() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var LastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var LastCol = ss.getLastColumn();
  var [header, ...values] = ss.getRange(1, 1, LastRow, LastCol).getValues();
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < LastRow - 1; i++) {
    var temp = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < LastCol; j++) {
      temp[header[j]] = values[i][j];
    }
    arr.push(temp);
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
}
```

- When this script is run, `arr` is `[{"FirstName":"Kim","LastName":"hana","Phone":"010-1234-5648","Email":"abc@gmail.com"}]`.
- As another apporach, I thought that you might be able to also use the following sample script.

  ```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var [header, ...values] = ss.getRange(1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var arr = values.map(r => header.reduce((o, h, j) => (o[h] = r[j], o), {}));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
  ```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to solve the problem by referring to the code you gave me.

Comment: @whytili Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your code creates separate objects in each iteration. Create an empty object for every Person, then add the properties you need.

This should look something like this:

```js
for(var i=2; i<=LastRow; i++){
    var payload = {}
    for(var j=1; j<=LastCol; j++){
        payload[arr[j-1]] = ss.getRange(i,j).getValue()};
    }
}
```